# generate presigned url sse-c s3

Tags: python, boto3

How to generate a `presigned url` to get an URL to an object using when `SSE-C` is used in python?

When I upload the file, this is what my code looks like

```
secret = '?D(G+KbPeSgVkYp3s6v9y$B&E)H@McQf' # just pasting here. In general, it's usually derived from .env file 
return client.put_object(
        Bucket=os.environ.get('S3_DOCS_BUCKET'),
        Key='koushik.jpg', # giving a random name for .jpg image file 
        Body=file,
        ContentType=fileobject.content_type,
        SSECustomerAlgorithm='AES256',
        SSECustomerKey=secret,
    )
```

Now, this uploads fine. But the problem is that I can't generate pre signed URL like this

```
url = client.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='get_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': os.environ.get('S3_DOCS_BUCKET'),
            'Key': 'koushik.jpg',
            'SSECustomerAlgorithm': 'AES256',
            'SSECustomerKey': '?D(G+KbPeSgVkYp3s6v9y$B&E)H@McQf', # just pasting here
        },
        ExpiresIn=3600,
    )
```

The key that it generates says that the signature doesn't match.
Now I've searched, at some places, it says that I've to provide the `SSECustomerKeyMD5` params as well.
I've tried doing that and still doesn't work.

```
url = client.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='get_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': os.environ.get('S3_DOCS_BUCKET'),
            'Key': 'koushik.jpg',
            'SSECustomerAlgorithm': 'AES256',
            'SSECustomerKey': '?D(G+KbPeSgVkYp3s6v9y$B&E)H@McQf', # just pasting here,
            'SSECustomerKeyMD5': hashlib.md5('?D(G+KbPeSgVkYp3s6v9y$B&E)H@McQf'.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        },
        ExpiresIn=3600,
    )
```

I've spent days but still can't get a working solution.
If anyone can, please show an working example of `file upload(a.k.a put_object)` by providing `SSECustomerKeyMD5`. I think that would help me a lot. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you set the signature version when creating the client? `client= boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')`

Comment: Tried this but didn't work as well